# Show $\|z_t-\frac{x}{\|x\|_2}\|_2=\mathcal O(a^t), \ t\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Let $(x_t)_{t\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\|x_t\|_2=\mathcal O(a^t), t\to \infty$ and $a \in (0,1)$.

Let $z_t:=\frac{x-x_t}{\|x-x_t\|_2}$ for $t \in \mathbb N$ and arbitrary $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$.

How do I show that $$\|z_t-\frac{x}{\|x\|_2}\|_2=\mathcal O(a^t), \ t\to \infty$$

Comment: Is $x$ fixed?$\,$

Comment: @zhw. It doesn't explicitly say so in the task but yes, I think that $x$ is fixed

Comment: One thing you should remark on is that $x-x_t=0$ is possible, rendering certain terms undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, since $a\in (0,1),$ that $x_t$ goes to $0$ and pick $t$ so large that $||x_t||<||x||$. Then, we can calculate

$$
||z_t-\frac{x}{||x||}||=||\frac{(x-x_t)||x||-x||x-x_t||}{||x-x_t||\cdot||x||}||
$$

Applying the triangle inequality in the numerator and the inverse triangle inequality in the denominator, we get

\begin{align}
||z_t-\frac{x}{||x||}|| &\leq \frac{\left|||x||\cdot(||x||-||x-x_t||)\right|+||x_t||\cdot||x||}{||x||^2-||x||_t||x||} \\
&\leq \frac{2||x_t||\cdot||x||}{||x||^2-||x||_t||x||},
\end{align}
where the second line uses the triangle inequality again to conclude that $|||x||-||x-x_t|||\leq |x_t|$.

Hence, for $t$ so large that $||x_t||<\frac{||x||}{2}$, we now see that if $||x_t||\leq C a^t$ for all $t\in \mathbb{N},$ we now have

$$
||z_t-\frac{x}{||x||}||\leq 4C\frac{a^t}{||x||}:= C_1 a^t
$$

This proves the desired.